# devise showing routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When trying to logout and login then showing this error but after logged in if i use the search in application layout its working fine.and why devise is searching for the following route?

```
{:action=>"search_result", :controller=>"devise/gadgets"}  


ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"search_result",  :controller=>"devise/gadgets", :id=>"search-form", :method=>"get"}):
```

gadgets/_searh.htm.erb

```
1: <%= form_tag(:controller => 'gadgets', :action => 'search_result', :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
2:   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search gadget" %>
3:   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil ,:class => "btn-small" %>
4: <% end %>
```

i am using devise for authentication. and when rendering the search form in application layout showing the above error

in application.html.erb, i am using the following div

```
<div id="search">
<%= render :partial => 'gadgets/search' %>
  </div>
```

and my route.rb is

```
 root :to => 'gadgets#index', :as => 'home'
 resources :gadgets

 get 'gadgets/index'

 get 'gadgets/show'

 get 'gadgets/edit'

 get 'gadgets/create'

 get 'gadgets/update'

 #get 'gadgets/search'

 #match '/search', to: '/gadgets/search_result', :via => [:get, :post]
 match "/gadgets/search_result", :via => [:get, :post]
 get 'gadgets/search_result'
 get 'gadgets/original'
 devise_for :users
 resources :users
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form to this:

```
<%= form_tag( { :controller => 'gadgets', :action => 'search_result' }, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search gadget" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil ,:class => "btn-small" %>
<% end %>
```

Both arguments for form_tag can be hashes.  The first argument can also be a string.  Since you're using the hash option you have to put brackets around it. Check the [Rails Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#multiple-hashes-in-form-helper-calls) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. while using devise in application.html.erb, if i use any method should use

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
```